# Java EE Web Application Glassfish error database not found

Tags: java, database, glassfish, enterprise

I am working on what is basically my first Java Enterprise-project following this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_zW27Y2boCo) ([source](http://www.mediafire.com/?0xf3zqp5s10a6o7)) tutorial. I have the exact same code as the guy in the video, but when trying to run my project I get this error code in the Glassfish server log:

> Allvarlig:   Exception while deploying the app [CRUDWebApplication] :
>   Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services -
>   2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
>
> Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a
>   connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: The
>   connection was refused because the database studentDB was not found.
>   Error Code: 0

So the problem is that the database studentDB can't be found and I cannot seem to figure out what may be the cause of this...